# How to hide the console when launching an application on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, console

There is a task, when launching the application, to display the text "The application is running" after pressing the enter button, the console should "close" but the application should remain running.
On windows, this can be done like this:

```
public static void HideConsole()
{
   var console = GetConsoleWindow();
   ShowWindow(console, nCmdShow: default);
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

However, such code will not work on linux, because it is a method call for windows. Is there any way to make a similar solution but only for linux?
I've been struggling with this for a long time and I can't find any solutions. Web project on .net 5

I tried to install wine, hoping that it would help, but nothing helped. I am testing the application both through WSL and installed virtual linux

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use the ProcessStartInfo :

```
Console.WriteLine("The application is running");
Console.ReadLine();

var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "dotnet",
        Arguments = "/path/to/your/application.dll",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    }
};

process.Start();

// Exit the current process
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```